# keep matlab view open after the function exits

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, point-clouds

I have a function that draws a point cloud. When I call the function, it shows the point cloud but as soon as the function exits, the view exits as well. How can I keep the view from exiting?

```
function drawPtCloud(ptCloud,colorLabels)
  player = pcplayer(xlimits, ylimits, zlimits);
  view(player, ptCloud,colorLabels);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axes is actually saved in the output argument of `pcplayer`. Take the output argument of `pcplayer`, i.e. `player`, as an output argument of your custom function `drawPtCloud`. i.e.

```
function player = drawPtCloud(ptCloud, colorLabels)
  player = pcplayer(xlimits, ylimits, zlimits);
  view(player, ptCloud,colorLabels);
end
```